# get posts equal to two meta_values

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to retrieve all posts where the meta_key status is equal to either correct or wrong. at the moment i've created below php variable however it shows all posts also posts where the meta_key is not equal to correct or wrong. What am i doing wrong?

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cat' => '4,5,6',
     'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'status',
            'meta_value' => 'wrong'
        ),
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'status',
            'meta_value' => 'correct'
        )
    )

);


$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$args = array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'cat' => '4,5,6',
 'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'meta_key' => 'status',
        'meta_value' => array('wrong','correct')
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
)
```

);